# How do I center text in an ASP.Net Hyperlink?

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.Net `Hyperlink` with a set height. The text is rendered at the top left of it. How do I vertically center it (-the text)?

(In C# I'd have: `label1.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;` . How is it done in ASP.Net?)

Tried the following but it doesn't work (neither on FF nor on IE).

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="~/WebForm1.aspx" runat="server" CssClass="MyClass" BackColor="White" 
Height="100px" Text="MyText"  Width="200px" ></asp:HyperLink>
</div>
</form>
```

And:

```
.MyClass
{
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood bu you can try to apply style attribute, something like: `<asp:HyperLink ... style="text-align:center;" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following styles to your `HyperLink`:

```
display:table-cell;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
```

If you are going to reuse that style is better to define a class:

```
<asp:HyperLink ... class="myClass" >HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
```

and then in your stylesheet:

```
.myClass{
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Or add the styles inline:

```
<asp:HyperLink ... style="display:table-cell;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" >HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: Thanks. But it only centers it horizontally.

Comment: for some reason, asp.net is adding an inline style to the hyperlink: style="display:inline-block" at runtime. A work around: add the style yourself inline: style="display:table-cell"

Comment: Thanks. Works now. (I didn't even know I could add inline `style` in ASP.Net. Intellisense didn't offer it.)

Answer (score 0):

Add folowing attributes to the CssClass or the inline style:

```
{
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;

 line-height: 32px;
}
```

note that replace "32px" with your height of Hyperlink.