# Asp hyperlink alignment

Tags: asp.net, gridview, hyperlink, center

I want the  hyperlink centered in the cell of GridView, this is the code for the grid column:

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ticket#"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"  SortExpression="ows_ID">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"  />
                <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:Hyperlink ID="hlID" Target="_parent" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ows_ID")%>' Font-Underline="false"  
                        NavigateUrl='<%#"Default.aspx?TktNo=" & Server.UrlEncode(Trim(Container.DataItem("ows_ID")))%>'/>

                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

HorizontalAlign="Center" doesn't work, nor does ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center". I have set style as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547291/how-do-i-center-text-in-an-asp-net-hyperlink) and that doesn't work either. FYI, bootstrap is involved also. What am I missing? Some setting in the grid declaration? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This can achieve by two methods

1- **try to use**
***< center >***

< ItemTemplate >
     ' Font-Underline="false" NavigateUrl='<%#"Default.aspx?TktNo=" & Server.UrlEncode(Trim(Container.DataItem("ows_ID")))%>'/>

```
            </ItemTemplate>
```

### ***< /center >***

2- Or you simply goto view souce file of your webpage 
try to find rendered html of hyperlink ....and then place your 
< asp:Hyperlink >
inside a < span class="class1"> < /span >

< style > .class1 { text-align:center; } 
< /style >

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS file, edit the style for td tag.

```
td
{
text-align: center;
}
```

GridView will be converted to table structure when rendered on webpage. So GridView takes styles of table

Comment: In that case a CSS class can be written to assign to only that datagrid. However I am not sure if it is required to acheive center alignment for that specific cell 
.datagrid td {
  text-align: center;
}

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with css:
Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/74Wxn/) from this post: [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21360634/how-to-center-text-in-td-with-anchor-link-that-fills-100)

And you have to add a css class to the table cell and wrap your css into the class, otherwise it will align all td's that way!

```
  td {
        height: 100%;
    }
    a {
        display: table;
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    span {
        display: table-cell;
        text-align:center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        background-color: red;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked was to place a div around the Hyperlink with alignment in the div.

```
                        <div style="text-align:center">
                     <asp:Hyperlink ID="hlID" Target="_parent" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ows_ID")%>' Font-Underline="false"  
                        NavigateUrl='<%#"Default.aspx?TktNo=" & Server.UrlEncode(Trim(Container.DataItem("ows_ID")))%>'/>
                    </div>
```